# Focus to a specific editable datagrid cell in wpf DataGrid on RowSelection

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpf-4.5

I have four columns in a datagrid and fourth column is templated and has textbox which is always editable.

What i am trying to achieve here is when a row selection changes the highlighted row's fourth cell which is editable and has textbox in it should get focus.

I am ok to get this done in codebehind or xaml.

Here is what i did:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid" SelectionChanged="MyGrid_OnSelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Str1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Str2}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Str3}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Str4}" GotFocus="UIElement_OnGotFocus" >
                            <TextBox.Style >
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">

                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell,AncestorLevel=1},Path=IsSelected}">
                                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

private void PopulateDummies()
    {
        int i = 0;
        List<SomeDummy> dummies = new List<SomeDummy>();
        while (i < 10)
        {
            dummies.Add(new SomeDummy
            {
                Str1 = string.Format("Str1:{0}", i),
                Str2 = string.Format("Str2:{0}", i),
                Str3 = string.Format("Str3:{0}", i),
                Str4 = string.Format("Str4:{0}", i)
            });
            i++;
        }
        MyGrid.ItemsSource = dummies;
    }

    private void MyGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void UIElement_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var txtB = sender as TextBox;
        txtB.Focus();
        txtB.SelectAll();
    }
```

Nothing seems to work. Not sure what is the reason. Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
txtB.Focus();
```

effectively replaces the DataGridCell by a TextEditory control. In order to do this, the view needs to be updated and therefore the UI-tread needs to run.
The SelectAll can not run until the editor is created, so run it as a separate Dispatcher-job and replace it with the following:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
    txtB.SelectAll();
}), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

This will do the trick and you don't need the SelctionChanged-event handler for this purpose.

Comment: That's unexpected: I created a new WPF application, put your code in the MainWindow.xaml and replaced the statement txtB.SelectAll() with my suggestion. Clicking on the cell (in column 4) set row selection, focus on the editor cell and now all text was selected as well. Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve.